# For every click different effect?

Tags: java

I have one problem. First - I HAVE AND I WILL HAVE JUST ONE BUTTON.
My problem is: How it can be for each button click different effect-animation.
So, when I first time click on button image goes down, then I second time click image goes from left to right, then I third time click image gone and then it repeat for fourth click image goes down(I can make animation left to right, animation down and then image gone.So I know how to do animation (effects), but I just do not know how to create for every click different effect on image)...

Answer (score 0):

- first read about ActioListeners
- then simply create a listener that uses a counter!

Each time you click the button the listener increases that counter. And you use different animations based on the current value of the counter. When the "last" animation took place - simply reset the counter to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
public class ButtonCycle extends JPanel {
    private int counter = 0;

    public ButtonCycle() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Next");
        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                switch(counter) {
                    case 0:
                        // "Go down"-animation code here
                        System.out.println("Go down");

                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // "Left->right"-animation code here
                        System.out.println("Left->right");

                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // "Disappearing"-animation code here
                        System.out.println("*poof*, now I'm gone");

                        counter = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        });

        add(btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Button cycling through animations");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,250));
                f.setContentPane(new ButtonCycle());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the **java.util.Random** class along with the **Random.nextInt()** method against values from 1 to 4 within the **ActionPerformed** event of your Button. Then, depending upon which value is randomly produced run a specific animation method, perhaps through a **switch/case** or **if** statements...whatever. Here is an example:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int value = (rnd.nextInt(4) + 1);
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            imageDown();
            break;
        case 2:
            imageLeftRight();
            break;
        case 3:
            imageGone();
            break;
        case 4:
            imageUp();
            break;
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer, you could use the **Math.random()** method., for example:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int value = 4 + (int)(Math.random() * (((1 - 2) - 4) + 1));
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            imageDown();
            break;
        case 2:
            imageLeftRight();
        break;
        case 3:
            imageGone();
            break;
        case 4:
            imageUp();
            break;
    }
}
```

Of course there will be times when the random number generated will be the very much the same as the number generated previously but then again you could use a class field to hold the previous random value and if the currently generated value is the same as the previously generated value then you can generate another within perhaps a **do/while** loop, for example:

```
private int previousValue = 0;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int value = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    do {
        value = (rnd.nextInt(4) + 1);
    } while (previousValue == value);
    previousValue = value;
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            imageDown();
            break;
        case 2:
            imageLeftRight();
            break;
        case 3:
            imageGone();
            break;
        case 4:
            imageUp();
            break;
    }
}
```